# Is OAuth 2.0 User-Agent Flow truly an Implicit Grant Type?

Tags: oauth2, authentication

Is the [Salesforce User-Agent Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_authenticate_overview.htm&type=5) truly an "Implicit" grant type? It can most definitely issue a refresh token.

And yet per [RFC 6749 Section 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) Implicit Grant documentation...

> The implicit grant type is used to obtain access tokens (it does not
> support the issuance of refresh tokens)...

and

> The authorization server MUST NOT issue a refresh token.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort of.

You only get the refresh token if you ask for it explicitly with `scope = refresh_token` and your flow meets other documented [constraints](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&type=5) such as custom protocol on the callback URL. We agree that this "extension" is not compliant with implicit grant type spec. If memory serves, it was created by SF for mobile apps a while ago. While some might still be using it, it's a legacy option as of now.

Implicit grant is no longer recommended. Lightly edited excerpt from [oAuth Security Best Current Practice (BCP)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics):

> The implicit grant and other response types
> causing the authorization server to issue access tokens in the
> authorization response are vulnerable to access token leakage and
> access token replay
>
> Moreover, no viable mechanism exists to cryptographically bind access
> tokens issued in the authorization response to a certain client.
> This makes replay detection for such
> access tokens at resource servers impossible.
>
> In order to avoid these issues, clients SHOULD NOT use the implicit
> grant or other response types issuing access
> tokens in the authorization response, unless access token injection
> in the authorization response is prevented and the aforementioned
> token leakage vectors are mitigated.
>
> Clients SHOULD instead use authorization code grant type or any
> other response type that causes the authorization server to issue
> access tokens in the token response.
>
> This allows the authorization server to detect replay
> attempts by attackers and generally reduces the attack surface since
> access tokens are not exposed in URLs.  It also allows the
> authorization server to sender-constrain the issued tokens (see next
> section).

Authorization code grant is known as Web Server flow in SF universe.