# Cannot Login Using OAuth2 User-Agent Flow

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps

I am building a proof of concept that allows the users of a desktop application, in this case JavaFX, to login utilizing their Salesforce credentials. Since the client is considered untrusted, we opted to use the OAuth2 User-Agent Flow. When providing a username and password at https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize we receive the following error:

`Please check your username and password. If you still can't log in, contact your Salesforce administrator.`

I have completed the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Verified that the username/password combination is correct using our web application.
2. Ensured that when the login URL above is loaded that we included the correct query parameters

   - response_type=token
   - client_id=<'consumer key' found in the connected app information>
   - redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.salesforce.com%2Fservices%2Foauth2%2Fsuccess
3. Relaxed IP restrictions of the Connected Apps OAuth2 Settings.
4. Ensured that our Connected App was added to the 'Assigned Connected Apps' of the user's respective User Profile.
5. I also tried it from my web browser to see if I could discover any error codes that I couldn't otherwise see from the JavaFX application. We still receive the same error as mentioned above.
6. Ensured that the Connected App OAuth2 settings allowed for users to self-authorize.

[image]

**Is there any other permissions or settings that I could be possibly missing that would prevent this user from logging in through my connected app?**

Comment: 1. Don't use this flow: [why](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273714/oauth-2-0-user-agent-flow-why-is-it-okay-to-keep-the-refresh-token-when-it-is-c) and [why 2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271280/is-oauth-2-0-user-agent-flow-truly-an-implicit-grant-type). 2. Without a refresh token, this flow is somewhat useless, it'll only work for the duration of the session. With a refresh token, it's even more insecure than with just the access token (see above).

Comment: 3. Reason for failure: take a look at Login History, it may have a better error message as a clue. For one, using `test.salesforce.com` (sandbox/pre-prod) as a redirect URL when you're going to `login.salesforce.com` (prod) will not work had you requested a refresh token...but you didn't do that. Nevertheless, try changing callback URL to `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success`.

Comment: thanks the for the feedback @identigral. My sessions will only need to live for a matter of minutes which is fine. With Web Server flow it would require that I deploy the consumer secret to untrusted machines. Is that not a worse scenario?

Comment: You don't need a secret for Web Server flow, it's optional and off by default.

Comment: thank you @identigral - I will try the web serverflow. I was testing in our full sandbox so I tried changing the login url to test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize with no success to make sure it atleast matched the redirect url as you alluded to. once I try the web server flow I will let you know how it goes and award credit for answering

Comment: ok funny enough i tried with a user that has admin privileges with the url alignment suggestion you made @identigral and it works. so it must be a permissions issue between my standard community users and my admin user