# OAuth 2.0 Web Server Flow and CORS problem

Tags: api, oauth2, cors

I try to communicate with the API Salesforce.

First, I call the URL: `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize`.
It gives me a code in the callback URL I gave on parameters.

Then, I try to call this code:

```
fetch( 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:1234',
        Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    mode: 'cors',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        code: decodeURI(code), // The code I retrieved calling the URL above
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
        redirect_uri: 'localhost:1234/myURL'
    })
}).then( response => {
    console.log('response: ' + response);
}).catch( (e) => {
    console.log('error: ' + e);
});
```

I also try with the URL: `https://mySalesforceDomain.lightning.force.com/services/oauth2/token` instead of `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token`.

But in both case, I arrive in the catch with the error: `Access to fetch at 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token' from origin 'http://localhost:1234' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.`

Do you have any idea how I can solve this CORS problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The user-agent flow (aka implicit flow in oAuth) is not recommended: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271280/is-oauth-2-0-user-agent-flow-truly-an-implicit-grant-type

Comment: You can enable CORS for oAuth endpoints as long as you're using My Domain or Experience Cloud URLs rather than `login.salesforce.com`:  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_endpoints_cors.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong flow. You should be using the [User-Agent](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&type=5) flow, in which you redirect to a login URL, and when the process completes, you'll be returned to the URL you specified as the callback URL with the access token and other details returned in the URL's hash. The example they give is:

```
https://www.customercontactinfo.com/user_callback.jsp#
access_token=00Dx0000000BV7z%21AR8AQBM8J_xr9kLqmZIRyQxZgLcM4HVi41aGtW0qW3JCzf5xd
TGGGSoVim8FfJkZEqxbjaFbberKGk8v8AnYrvChG4qJbQo8&
refresh_token=5Aep8614iLM.Dq661ePDmPEgaAW9Oh_L3JKkDpB4xReb54_pZfVti1dPEk8aimw4Hr9ne7VXXVSIQ%3D%3D&
instance_url=https://yourInstance.salesforce.com&
id=https://login.salesforce.com%2Fid%2F00Dx0000000BV7z%2F005x00000012Q9P&
issued_at=1278448101416&
signature=miQQ1J4sdMPiduBsvyRYPCDozqhe43KRc1i9LmZHR70%3D&
scope=id+api+refresh_token&
token_type=Bearer&
state=mystate
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. Now, I can get the `access_token` correctly. Another question is about the `Selected OAuth Scopes` in the `Manage Connected Apps` setup. I just want to retrieve Salesforce objects and their fields with some SOQL queries after the user is connected with this User-Agent flow. What are the items I need to put in the `Selected OAuth Scopes` list?

Comment: @SF_user Just "api" should be sufficient.

Comment: Ok thank you. But a comment above says that it is not a recommanded workflow, that's right?

Comment: @SF_user There is a Best Current Practice that states this type of flow shouldn't be used because of security concerns. While true, simply remembering to use window.location.replace should mitigate most of the concerns. If you still want to use Web Server flow, you can, but the calls should be made from the server, not the client. As written, your original code would also be a security concern, because your client secret is no longer a secret.

Comment: @SF_user The client secret must be treated as a password, because it is, in a sense, a password. The User Agent flow gets around this by not requiring a client secret to work correctly. The UA flow also has other security considerations, such as requiring the redirect URI to match, etc. So, either move the access token logic to the server with WS flow, or use the UA flow and mitigate token leaks via window.location.replace.

Comment: I also have CORS problem with this workflow when I call the `instance_URL`. Do I need to put some URLs in SalesForce settings? I'm testing with a localhost URL.

Comment: @SF_user I thought you were running the code on localhost? If so, I'm not sure you can add that to Salesforce. You should use a publicly available Internet host for development (e.g. Heroku) if you want to add CORS in Salesforce.

Comment: Yes I'm testing it on localhost. Adding the URL in the CORS settings make the job. But now I have the access_token on the URL. I want to delete it. I check the replace() as you said but it refresh the page and I lose all my variables. I'm not sure to really understand how I can do this! Do you have any example please?

Comment: @SF_user You're meant to store the access token somewhere before you use window.location.replace.

Comment: ok I do that. And I can directly call a web service, for example to get all accounts without call the authorize web service before if i have a valid access_token? Or this step is mandatory?